# Is this code safe for search box or no?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
  $output = '';
  $search = "%{$_POST['query']}%";

 $stmt = $con->prepare(" SELECT * FROM tables WHERE cat_name LIKE ?              
 LIMIT 3");

 $stmt->bind_param("s",$search);
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$output .= '
<a href="tables.php?id='.$row['cat_id'] .'" 
class="searchLinksStyle w3-col l12  w3-card-4 w3-round-large w3-button" 
>'.$row['cat_name'].'</a>';
 }
echo $output;
```

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915952/can-i-fully-prevent-sql-injection-by-pdo-prepared-statement-without-bind-param and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426172/what-does-bind-param-accomplish

Comment: code review is off-topic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You forgot to html-escape your output => potential XSS vulnerability
- When the query includes characters like `%` they will be treated as special characters, not as literal characters. I don't know the characteristics of the MySQL wildcard engine well enough to tell if that enables a DoS attack (e.g. via catastrophic backtracking).

Comment: could you please clear how to html-escape my output ?

Comment: @Beginner, have a look here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

- From a SQL injection side, you should be safe since you are prepared statement.

Please see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426172/what-does-bind-param-accomplish).

From the accepted answer:

> The main principle there is using prepared statement which is designed
>   for sending safe query to db server, this can be done by escaping user
>   input which is not part of the real query, and also checking the query
>   without any (where clause) to check the validity of the query before
>   using any parameters.

- The query is limited to three results and is on a single value (***cat_name***) which will reduces the possibility of a DOS style attack. As an example:

If the query could be forced to take a very long time to execute, a remote attacker could potentially use a lot of database connections and force excessive load on your database.

Comment: you mean the code is safe inshallah ?

Comment: The other answer mentions that you must sanitise the output. If user A saves a value with HTML or JavaScript in the database, this could be outputed on user B's browser. XSS.